# Preview not working on MobileFirst Platform Foundation Server 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-console

On the MobileFirst Server Platform Foundation 7.0, the Preview is not working in the console. On the Eclipse development side, all is working well.

The error message is the following:
[image: Error Message]

Here is the error in the log:

```
[4/10/15 12:12:55:267 CEST] 00000027 org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor             I The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (404 - Not Found) with message 'null' while processing GET request sent to http://10.3.20.64:9080/catalogmanagerfull/authorization/v1/clients/preview
```

The application can use the server without any issue. It's really only the Preview in the console that is not working. The Application Server is a WAS Liberty profile running on Linux.

In a MobileFirst Server V6.3, the same project has no issue.

Comment: Please supply a project that recreates this issue so that we could debug it.

Comment: Also supply the messages.log from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview is not meant to work in a production environment, however the preview button was still there in the GM release of MFPF 7.0.

I think you might have hit APAR PI37266:

> MFP OPERATIONS CONSOLE: PREVIEW OF COMMON RESOURCES BUTTON MUST BE
>   HIDDEN IN PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT

So, you should update your installation to the latest available 7.0 iFix, whereh the preview button is not longer available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I installed the iFix 7.0.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201504171448 but still have the Preview Button. Maybe next iFix

Comment: @Aymeric, 1) Try to force-clear your browser's cache to see if this helps. 2) Please edit the question with the result of the failed request (can be seen in the Chrome DevTools > Network view > Preview tab; it should show a list of properties for the request/response, one of them being "developmentMode:true/false").

Comment: My big mistake : I installed the iFix (via IBM Installation Manager) but I did not redeploy the new modules to my liberty server. The key point was : ant -f myfile adminstall. Now the Preview button is not available. @Idan, I found the developmentMode set to false but other variables, like productVersion where I saw that my version was without the iFix. Sorry for missing that step.