# Not able to deploy .adapter on MobileFirst Platform Operations Console

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have installed the IBM Mobile First Platform server 7.0 on Windows 2012R2.
I am using tomcat 7 as application server and Oracle 11g as DB.
I am able to deploy .wlapp files on the console but when I deploy any adapter on console it stuck saying "Deploying adapter-name.adapter..." but nothing happens.

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: And in the server logs you see...?

Comment: yes have error logs each time it says  FAILURE=>UndeclaredThrowableException
FAILURE=>PermGen space

Comment: Great. Increase the permgen memory that is allocated to your tomcat instance.

Comment: ok i'll try doing that. Thanks.

Comment: yes increasing permgen memory worked but I am facing another problem now when I am trying to login to app it says "POST http://localhost:8080/XXX_Mobile/authorization/v1/clients/preview 404 (Not Found)" and Client registration failed with error: {"status":404,"responseHeaders":{"Date":"Fri, 17 Apr 2015 14:59:04 GMT","Content-Length":"0","Server":"Apache-Coyote/1.1"},"responseText":"","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.","invocationContext":null}

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607565/preview-not-working-on-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-server-7-0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75525/discussion-between-sanket-k-and-idan-adar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Tomcat FAQ on [How to deal with OutOfMemory errors](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory):

> A webapp that uses lots of libraries with many dependencies, or a
>   server maintaining lots of webapps could exhauste the JVM PermGen
>   space. This space is where the VM stores the classes and methods data.
>   In those cases, the fix is to increase this size. The Sun VM has the
>   flag -XX:MaxPermSize that allows to set its size (the default value is
>   64M)

- Edit the CATALINA_OPTS file
- Use an appropriate amount of memory for `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`
- Also refer this question (and many others, google): See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003986/1530814
- Don't forget to restart the application server