# Preview Mode on Production Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

We've recently migrated from 5.0.6 Worklight. The preview mode was working in 5.0.6 console. After migrating to 7.0 and uploading the common.wlapp file, I am getting the following errors and cannot preview the app. Should the  preview mode work on a production MobileFirst Platform server version 7.0?
I use this for quick testing of our mobile app and connectivity for our adapters.

```
POST http://serverurl/AppName/authorization/v1/clients/preview 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no more Preview mode in a production environment, however there was a bug in the initial release of v7.0 where the preview button was still available while the underlying code is no longer there.

Make sure you to apply the latest iFix release to your server installation.
It can be downloaded from IBM Fix Central.

Related question:

- [Preview not working on MobileFirst Platform Foundation Server 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607565/preview-not-working-on-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-server-7-0)